# How many people are going / coming?

Tags: word-choice

Asked about if you can come to the party and you want to know the number of the people who’ll attend it, which is more commonly used, “How many people are going?” or “How many people are coming?”

Comment: It depends on whether you're a host or a guest and whether you're already at the party. If you've been invited, and want to know how many other guests will attend, use *going*. If you're one of multiple hosts, and want to know how many people have already RSVPed, you'd use *coming*. And if you're a guest who arrives early at a party and want to know how many more guests will probably arrive you would also use *coming*.

Comment: See also [Should I use 'coming' or 'going'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/139130/should-i-use-coming-or-going)?

Comment: See also [the use of 'going' and 'coming' in a given situation](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/253380/the-use-of-going-vs-coming-in-a-given-situation)

Comment: See also [Is it I'm going or I'm going...](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/324940/is-it-im-coming-or-going-as-i-promised)

Comment: Heck, just see [coming going](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=Coming+going+) of this site. I can't imagine none of these possible duplicates weren't suggested to you when you wrote your question.